# Read specific data from XML using Java (DOM)

Tags: java, xml, dom

I want to extrat some data from an invoice (XML) using Java. I'm using the example on this link (https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)
The problem is my XML doesn't look like the one in the example, here is mine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:bfa2="http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/addenda/bf/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" NumCtaPago="4007" LugarExpedicion="CUAJIMALPA DE MORELOS,CIUDAD DE MEXICO" metodoDePago="99" tipoDeComprobante="ingreso" total="2490" subTotal="2146.55" fecha="2016-12-14T10:23:08" folio="57318" serie="BT" version="3.2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/addenda/bf/2 http://www.buzonfiscal.com/schema/xsd/Addenda_BF_v20.xsd">
   <cfdi:Emisor nombre="BEST BUY STORES S. DE R.L. DE C.V." rfc="BBS070606D33">
      <cfdi:DomicilioFiscal codigoPostal="05348" pais="MEXICO" estado="CIUDAD DE MEXICO" municipio="CUAJIMALPA DE MORELOS" referencia="EDIFICIO CENTURY PLAZA" colonia="SANTA FE CUAJIMALPA" noInterior="PISO 2 OFNA 202 Y 203 P3 Y P4" noExterior="440" calle="AV. SANTA FE" />
      <cfdi:ExpedidoEn codigoPostal="05348" pais="MEXICO" estado="CIUDAD DE MEXICO" municipio="CUAJIMALPA DE MORELOS" colonia="SANTA FE" calle="AVENIDA SANTA FE NO. 440 PISO 2 (OFICINA 203 Y 204),PISO 3 Y PISO 4" />
      <cfdi:RegimenFiscal Regimen="Regimen General de Ley Personas Morales" />
   </cfdi:Emisor>
   <cfdi:Receptor nombre="VIALCOMA S.A DE C.V" rfc="VIA8011248W0">
      <cfdi:Domicilio codigoPostal="54080" pais="México" estado="Estado de México" municipio="Tlalnepantla de Baz" referencia="VIALCOMA S.A. de C.V." localidad="Tlalnepantla de Baz" colonia="EL MIRADOR" noExterior="107" calle="AV. GUSTAVO BAZ " />
   </cfdi:Receptor>
   <cfdi:Conceptos>
      <cfdi:Concepto importe="2146.55" valorUnitario="2146.55" descripcion="PANASONIC PHONE KX-PRD260MEB" noIdentificacion="000000001000189023" unidad="PZA" cantidad="1" />
   </cfdi:Conceptos>
   <cfdi:Impuestos totalImpuestosTrasladados="343.45">
      <cfdi:Traslados>
         <cfdi:Traslado importe="343.45" tasa="16.0" impuesto="IVA" />
      </cfdi:Traslados>
   </cfdi:Impuestos>
   <cfdi:Complemento>
      <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigital.xsd" UUID="2e36935c-4948-4f7b-9b29-477546aa2922" version="1.0" />
   </cfdi:Complemento>
   <cfdi:Addenda>
      <bfa2:AddendaBuzonFiscal version="2.0">
         <bfa2:Receptor email="" />
         <bfa2:TipoDocumento descripcion="Factura" nombreCorto="FAC" />
         <bfa2:CFD totalConLetra="Dos mil cuatrocientos noventa pesos 00/100 M.N." fechaEnvio="2016-12-12T10:42:15-06:00" />
         <bfa2:Extra valor="02028001014520161212" atributo="numTicket" />
      </bfa2:AddendaBuzonFiscal>
   </cfdi:Addenda>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

I want to get (print on console) the data on "folio" "serie" and "UUID"

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Please show your code. Without it is impossible to help.

Comment: "I'm using the example on this link... The problem is my XML doesn't look like the one in the example". This seems to illustrate a pretty flawed strategy for how to become proficient in using the technology. You'll never master programming if your approach is to search for the web for an example that does exactly what you want and then ask on SO if you can't find one. You need to read some books, master the concepts, learn to apply them to your own problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should give your desire output.This example is based on DOM parser as you have provide.

```
   System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

   NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("cfdi:Comprobante");

   org.w3c.dom.Node nNode = nList.item(0);

   System.out.println("folio: " + ((Element) nNode).getAttribute("folio"));
   System.out.println("serie: " + ((Element) nNode).getAttribute("serie"));

   NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("cfdi:Complemento");
   for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    NodeList child = list.item(i).getChildNodes();
    for (int j = 0; j < child.getLength(); j++) {
     if (child.item(j).getNodeName().equals("tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital")) {
      String uuid = ((Element)(child.item(j))).getAttribute("UUID");
      System.out.println("UUID : " + uuid);
     }
    }
   }
```

console output:

```
Root element :cfdi:Comprobante
----------------------------
folio: 57318
serie: BT
UUID : 2e36935c-4948-4f7b-9b29-477546aa2922
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked the way i wanted. Now with this example I can use the data at will.